# Getting a valueerror on merging two dataframes in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, valueerror

I tried to merge two dataframes using panda but this is the error code that I get:

*ValueError: You are trying to merge on datetime64[ns] and datetime64[ns, UTC] columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat*

I have tried different solutions found online but nothing works!! The code has been provided to me and it seems to work on other PCs but not on my computer.

This is my code:

```
import sys
import os
from datetime import datetime
import numpy  as np
import pandas as pd


# --------------------------------------------------------------------
# -- price, consumption and production                              --
# --------------------------------------------------------------------

fn = '../data/np_data.csv'
if os.path.isfile(fn):
    df_data = pd.read_csv(fn,header=[0],parse_dates=[0])
   
else:
    sys.exit('Could not open data file {}̈́'.format(fn))


# --------------------------------------------------------------------
# -- temp. data                                               --
# --------------------------------------------------------------------

fn = '../data/temp.csv'
if os.path.isfile(fn):
    dtemp = pd.read_csv(fn,header=[0],parse_dates=[0])
   
else:
    sys.exit('Could not open data file {}̈́'.format(fn))


# --------------------------------------------------------------------
# --  price data                                              --
# --   first date: 2014-01-13                                       --
# --   last  date: 2020-02-01                                       --
# --------------------------------------------------------------------

fn = '../data/eprice.csv'
if os.path.isfile(fn):
    eprice = pd.read_csv(fn,header=[0])
   
else:
    sys.exit('Could not open data file {}̈́'.format(fn))


# --------------------------------------------------------------------
# -- combine dataframes (and save as CSV file)                      --
# --------------------------------------------------------------------

#

df= df_data.merge(dtemp, on='time',how='left')      ## This is where I get the error.

print(df.info())
print(eprice.info())

#
# add eprice
df = df.merge(eprice, on='date', how='left')

#
# eprice available only available on trading days
#   fills in missing values, last observation is used
  df = df.fillna(method='ffill')

#
# keep only the relevant time period
df = df[df.date > '2014-01-23']
df = df[df.date < '2020-02-01']


df.to_csv('../data/my_data.csv',index=False)
```

The datasets that have been imported look normal with expected number of columns and observations. The version that I have in Panda is 1.0.3

## Edit:

this is the output (df) when I first merge df_data and dtemp.

```
                           time  price_sys  price_no1  ...  temp_no3  temp_no4  temp_no5
0 2014-01-23 00:00:00+00:00      32.08      32.08  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN
1 2014-01-24 00:00:00+00:00      31.56      31.60  ...      -2.5      -8.7       2.5
2 2014-01-24 00:00:00+00:00      30.96      31.02  ...      -2.5      -8.7       2.5
3 2014-01-24 00:00:00+00:00      30.84      30.79  ...      -2.5      -8.7       2.5
4 2014-01-24 00:00:00+00:00      31.58      31.10  ...      -2.5      -8.7       2.5

[5 rows x 25 columns]
```

This is the output for eprice before I merge:

```
    <bound method NDFrame.head of                      date  gas price  oil price  coal price  carbon price
0     2014-01-24 00:00:00      66.00     107.88       79.42          6.89
1     2014-01-27 00:00:00      64.20     106.69       79.43          7.04
2     2014-01-28 00:00:00      63.75     107.41       79.29          7.20
3     2014-01-29 00:00:00      63.20     107.85       78.52          7.21
4     2014-01-30 00:00:00      62.60     107.95       78.18          7.46
                  ...        ...        ...         ...           ...
1608  2020-03-25 00:00:00      22.30      27.39       67.81         17.51
1609  2020-03-26 00:00:00      21.55      26.34       70.35         17.35
1610  2020-03-27 00:00:00      18.90      24.93       72.46         16.39
1611  2020-03-30 00:00:00      19.20      22.76       71.63         17.06
1612  2020-03-31 00:00:00      18.00      22.74       71.13         17.68

[1613 rows x 5 columns]>
```

This is what happends when I merge df and eprice:

```
    <bound method NDFrame.head of                      date  gas price  oil price  coal price  carbon price
0     2014-01-24 00:00:00      66.00     107.88       79.42          6.89
1     2014-01-27 00:00:00      64.20     106.69       79.43          7.04
2     2014-01-28 00:00:00      63.75     107.41       79.29          7.20
3     2014-01-29 00:00:00      63.20     107.85       78.52          7.21
4     2014-01-30 00:00:00      62.60     107.95       78.18          7.46
                  ...        ...        ...         ...           ...
1608  2020-03-25 00:00:00      22.30      27.39       67.81         17.51
1609  2020-03-26 00:00:00      21.55      26.34       70.35         17.35
1610  2020-03-27 00:00:00      18.90      24.93       72.46         16.39
1611  2020-03-30 00:00:00      19.20      22.76       71.63         17.06
1612  2020-03-31 00:00:00      18.00      22.74       71.13         17.68

[1613 rows x 5 columns]>
                       time  price_sys  ...  coal price  carbon price
0 2014-01-23 00:00:00+00:00      32.08  ...         NaN           NaN
1 2014-01-24 00:00:00+00:00      31.56  ...         NaN           NaN
2 2014-01-24 00:00:00+00:00      30.96  ...         NaN           NaN
3 2014-01-24 00:00:00+00:00      30.84  ...         NaN           NaN
4 2014-01-24 00:00:00+00:00      31.58  ...         NaN           NaN

[5 rows x 29 columns]
```

Comment: wait! I see only 'time' in df and 'date' in eprice. Just to confirm  - are you sure it doesn't have to be `...merge(...,left_on='time',right_on='date')`?

Although you mentioned that `df.merge(eprice.head(),...` works?

Comment: @ParthaMandal, I have date as a column in df also :D which is how I intended to merge eprice with df. Do you mean when merging to get df? or when merging df with eprice? Let me try the latter and see what I get. *Btw, your help is truly appreciated. Thank you!!!


Edit:

Comment: Update:
I just did what you suggested but got the same valueerror as I did in the start.
When I just took df.info, I see that some of the columns are float64 and others are int64 except for date-column (object) and time (datetime64[ns, UTC]) (. Can that be the reason why I am getting issues?

Comment: Yeah, worth looking into. If you really don't need `time`, I would suggest getting it to only date level like that : `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time']).dt.date` (for all the dataframes) [Or you could just convert your `date` column (in eprice) to `datetime64...`] (using the code in answer)

Comment: What finally worked was to transform the 'date' and 'time' column before merging for both df and eprice. When l later did the fillna.method to fill missing values it went through without a problem. Thank you for your help Partha! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing `df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], utc = True)` on both the time columns before joining (or rather the one without UTC needs to go through this!)

Comment: It now worked luckily but there is another problem. After having successfully merged the df_data and dtemp  using the tip that you provided, I see that merging the results with eprice after causes the eprice observations to dissappear. I get NaN where I instead should have a number.  If I take eprice.head() before I merge with df. I get the observations as expected. What can I do?

Comment: can you share the outputs you are getting (in both the cases). Also, is this how you are merging : `df = df.merge(eprice, on='date', how='left')`? So, your df has both 'date' and 'time' columns?

Comment: @ Partha Mandal . Correct, the function df has both 'date' and 'time' columns. How can I share the output without manually doing it? I tried several ways but couldnt do it correctly.

To put it this way, the output when I first merge looks as expected with the values from both dataframes merged into one through the newly defined df. The problem emerges when I try to merge again, the eprice file with the df, it is as if all values dissappear when I do that :/

Comment: can you do a `print(df.head()` for both the datasets and add that into your question. Looking at the data would help  undetstand what might be going wrong!